# How do I implement views count for video in js upon firebase database?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement view-count of my video using firebase database.
I want to have a global variable for instance `counterViews` and save it in the database. Every time a video is played (only on the first click on the button) then I'll increment `counterViews` by one, then save the new value to the database.

How can I implement this? This is my code so far.

```js
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAAjDBeVj92tvR5NnKouT4pE31Qb7v-gag",
  authDomain: "ucb-clickcount.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://ucb-clickcount.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ucb-clickcount",
  storageBucket: "ucb-clickcount.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "321461348082"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); // here's gettin my video's placeholder
var counter = 0;
```

Comment: How about the part where you click on the button?

Comment: I thought in that direction but couldn't succeed to implement it ..

Comment: I thought in that direction but didn't succeed to implement it